# Cfdocument of pdf type not showing images?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdocument

Through cfdocument I am generating a pdf file and sending the same to the user. But the images are not appearing on that pdf document.

I am not sure what type path i should use absolute/relative and what should be the value of localurl attribute?

Comment: You should post the code that you are using. It's easier to help you if we can see exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

We have had issues in the past with images not showing up in PDFs generated using CFDOCUMENT.  Our issue was that our HTTP server required the use of an IP address for internal ColdFusion requests.

Although we could view the image in the browser using either URL, CFDOCUMENT couldn't access the images using the domain name.  This might be your issue.

```
// works in browser ~ does not work in cfdocument
http: //mydomain.com/myimage.gif

// works in browser ~ works in cfdocument
http: //123.456.789.0/myimage.gif
```

Answer (score 2):

you can reference the file location on the server if you are hosting it.

```
<img src="file:///#ExpandPath('/exportPages/img/spritelogo.gif')#">
```

note: The 3 slashes are not a typo.

You can read a bit more at [Team Ravenglass](http://www.ravenglass.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/9/Including-Images-in-a-PDF-created-in-CFDOCUMENT)